# Subsonic Paging using stored procedure

Tags: subsonic

I have seen the video of paging using subsonic
http://subsonicproject.com/querying/webcast-using-paging/

I am calling a stored procedure to retrieve the data. Is it possible for me to use paging? Please give me few samples.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the stored procedures and can you modify them?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add paging to your stored procedure. Methods to accomplish this vary based on which database you're using. I would capture the SQL generated by a paged query, copy that SQL into a new sproc, add params for page number and page size, then access the Stored procedure proxy method for your newly-created sproc.